# Theoretically understanding the algorithmic solution to this Quadratically Constrained Quadratic Optimization Problem

Tags: convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I have a simple QCQP problem to solve:

$\min_{t} x(t)^{T}Ax(t)$ subject to constraints $x(t)^{T}Ax(t) > 1 $ where A is a positive definite matrix and $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is some time parameterized curve.

While technically this is a convex QCQP, notice that the cost and the constraint are the same mathematical terms. This means that if I use a gradient descent algorithm, I can ignore the constraint and if the cost goes below or equal to 1, I can simply terminate the algorithm !
But is this theoretically the right way to approach the problem? How can this be explained in terms of the Kuch Tucker optimality conditions? Is there a specific name for a problem of this sort?

Comment: Yes. You seek the first time the curve exits the the ellipsoid $E := \{x | x^TAx \le 1\}$, and your approach is the "theoretically right way" to approach the problem.

Comment: This really is not a convex QCQP; the constraint is not convex. And unless unless $x$ is linear in $t$ it is not a QCQP. But I agree with the other commenter.